# Colouring lines in ggplot returns "negative subscripts" errors

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using this toy example;

```
ddd <- c("31/03/1995","30/04/1995","31/05/1995","31/08/2013","30/09/2013","31/10/2013","30/11/2013")
rrr <- c("returns.1","returns.1","returns.1","returns.5","returns.5","returns.5","returns.5")
vvv <- c(-0.204598992791177,3.01855013302475,6.3888266761452,-1.21353731479968,7.20845451481339,3.97428317355226,0.0155720962396065)

df <- cbind(ddd,rrr,vvv)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df$vvv  <-  as.numeric(df$vvv)
```

I able to plot my data (with no legend/labels for the lines), using the below

```
ggplot(data=DF,aes(x=ddd,y=vvv)) +
geom_line(aes(group=rrr))
```

But i wish to add colours/legends so I modify the above with ;

```
ggplot(data=DF,aes(x=ddd,y=vvv)) +
geom_line(aes(group=rrr)) +
geom_line(aes(colour=rrr))
```

But this returns the following error

```
Error in x[1:min(n, length(x))] : 
only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Any idea what the issue is, or what I should check in my data frame?

Comment: Without data it is hard to say why you get this error. One thing is that you don't need two geom_line() calls - use geom_line(aes(group=variable,colour=variable))

Comment: I realise I do not need two calls - just did this for clarity. I have added a simple data frame to the above. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Because `ddd` is a factor, you need to use both `group` and `colour` on the *same* layer.  In your example, you are using two layers, one without `group`, and one without `colour`:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=ddd,y=vvv)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=rrr, colour=rrr))
```

[image]

An alternative is to convert your dates into date format instead of factor, though with your dates so far apart you may want to facet by `rrr` (also, note this way stuff actually shows up in the correct order):

```
df$ddd <- as.Date(df$ddd, format="%d/%m/%Y")
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=ddd,y=vvv)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=rrr)) +
  facet_wrap(~ rrr, scales="free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think using the same layer is the only issue. I restarted R and ran < rm(list=ls()) > to remove all data, and reran the example again.

Using your suggestion then worked, but using the code that uses different layers, I got a different error < 
Error in get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...) : 
  Mapping should be a list of unevaluated mappings created by aes or aes_string >
, which is clearly different from the above.

Comment: @JSB, I didn't comment on this originally, but your defined dataframe is `df`, and the one in the plot is `DF`.  Notice how I refer to `df` not `DF` in the ggplot call.  Maybe that's part of the problem?

Comment: That was a typo on my part. Removing all libraries and reloading ggplot seemed to get this to work. From what I can gather there seems to be a conflict between ggplot2 and the other libraries I am using...